# error en Async y Await

Tags: async

hola estoy tratando de replicar el codigo de un curso para crear una red social con JS Angular y mongo DB el problema es que estoy atorado en la siguiente linea de codigo:

}

```
//Conseguir datos de un usuario
function getUser(req, res){
    var userId = req.params.id;

    User.findById(userId, (err, user) => {
        if(err) return res.status(500).send({message: 'Error en la peticion'});

        if(!user) return res.status(404).send({message: 'El usuario no existe'});

        followThisUser(req.user.sub, userId).then((value) => {
            return res.status(200).send({user,value});

        });

    });
}

async function followThisUser(identity_user_id, user_id){
    var following = await Follow.findOne({"user":identity_user_id, "followed":user_id}).exec((err, follow) => {
            if(err) return handleError(err);
            return follow;
        });

    var followed = await Follow.findOne({"user":user_id, "followed":identity_user_id}).exec((err, follow) => {
            if(err) return handleError(err);
            return follow;
        });

    return {
        following: following,
        followed: followed
    };
}
```

no me devuelve el Following ni el Followed cuando corro la api en Postman, me pueden indicar que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Que error devuelve postman?

Comment: Hola gbianchi  buenas noches, no me arroja un error lo unico que me devuelve es el value pero sin los valores solicitados en el Async y Await que son Folling y Followed